# Export env variables to grandchild jobs

Tags: upstart

I have a set of upstart scripts, generated by foreman from a Procfile, to start my web service and async task queue worker. The way foreman generates the scripts is as follows:

- app
- app-web
- app-web-1
- app-worker
- app-worker-1

where "app-web" and "app-worker" are set to start on starting "app", and "app-web-1" and "app-worker-1" are set to start on starting "app-web" and "app-worker" respectively. As I understand it, this structure is to allow you to easily add further web and worker processes when load increases, while still managing the whole thing from the top-level "app" job.

So, I want to set various environment variables in my jobs. I can of course put them directly into the bottom-level scripts, but it would be better to put them in the top level so they only have to be defined once. I thought I would be able to do this in app.conf by simply using `env` and `export`:

```
env FOO=bar
export FOO
```

but this doesn't seem to work: it's fine if I put it in the middle "app-web" job, but if I put in the top-level "app" it doesn't get inherited by the bottom-level "app-web-1". So, my second attempt was to put that in the top-level script, and then try and re-export in the middle one with just `export FOO`, but this doesn't work either.

Is it possible to do what I want, or should I simply settle for defining the variables in multiple places?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in two way: `export` variable in the middle script or save it in file and source it in lowest script.

I tested this example on lubuntu 12.04:

**myapp.conf** is the main script and export `MYAPP_FOO` variable:

```
# myapp - 
description "export environment variable"
env MYAPP_FOO=bar
export MYAPP_FOO

task
console log
script
    exec  echo "$MYAPP_FOO - myapp" 
end script
```

**app-web.conf** is the middle script that export parent's variable and define and export `MYAPP_FOO1`

```
# app-web - 
description "export environment variable"
start on starting myapp
env MYAPP_FOO1=bar1
export MYAPP_FOO1
export MYAPP_FOO

task
console log
script  
   exec  echo "$MYAPP_FOO - app-web - $MYAPP_FOO1" 
end script
```

Finally **app-web1.conf** print variable:

```
# app-web1 - 
description "export environment variable"
start on starting app-web

task
console log
script  
   exec  echo "$MYAPP_FOO - app-web1 - $MYAPP_FOO1" 
end script
```

I used `sudo start myapp` and the result in `/var/log/upstart/app-web1.log` is:

```
bar - app-web1 - bar1
```

Another approach is to define your variable in file and source it where you need:

```
# app-web1 - 
description "export environment variable"
start on starting app-web

task
console log
script  
   . /path/where/you/want/environmentFile
   exec  echo "$MYAPP_FOO - app-web1 - $MYAPP_FOO1" 
end script
```

Or you can create `environmentFile` in the middle script:

```
# app-web - 
description "export environment variable"
start on starting myapp
env MYAPP_FOO1=bar1

task
console log
script 
   env | grep MYAPP_ > /path/where/you/want/environmentFile 
   exec  echo "$MYAPP_FOO - app-web - $MYAPP_FOO1" 
end script
```